# how to get the prompt in FTP Client using Apache commons

Tags: java, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I am developing a client application to connect to a host/server by FTP/TELNET or it could be any protocol. It needs to be a generic app. I am using apache commons. Using Apache commons I was able to connect to FTP server and login. But how do I get a "ftp>" ftp prompt on screen so that the user issues the commands.
Is there a way to get the ftp> prompt in my application so that an user keys in the commands and gets the required output on screen.
Please assist.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: are you trying to implement an ftp client ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Apache commons to connect to the server using your own custom code behind you'll need to provide your own interface from your application.

If you are executing a cmd line ftp client through your code you'll still need to provide your own interface and then read and write the users requests/responses to/from it by redirecting stdin and stdout.